# How can I decide if I should use a title (Mr./Ms.) when e-mailing a prospective employer?

Tags: professionalism, email, united-states

I have been corresponding with several potential employers, but I'm not sure about the appropriate way to address the representative. How should I determine how to address them ("John", "Mr. Smith", "Mr. John Smith", "John Smith", etc.) I've never met these people and do not know what is typical in the company they work for.

I have received several e-mails addressing me by my first name and often with a greeting (e.g. "Hi [Firstname]") rather than by referring to me by my last name (e.g. "Mr. [Lastname]"). Should I follow their lead, or should I err on the conservative side the first time I address them to test the waters? What are some ways to evaluate the proper title to use?

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted. If there is a problem or it could be revised to better fit with the site guidelines, let me know. I can't improve it if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Chances are it received a downvote because it is a bit broad. Each culture/workplace has very different standards of 'acceptable'. The answer to this will be very different if you're working as a welder in a Korean oil refinery vs. a Manhattan law firm vs. a resort in Bali. It will be very different if the employer is a 60 year-old Japanese man than if it is a 14 year-old prodigy. In other words, how the heck can we answer as it currently is?

Comment: 99% of the answers would be opinion-based, and cover only a small segment of potential employers. If you specify your specific situation, it will likely not be so useful to future visitors. The best bet is to make the question more general, "How can I evaluate which title to use when sending e-mails to potential employers?" without asking what is 'typical' or for something authoritative. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: @jmac I've changed the answer to indicate that, in my situation, it is for United States software companies. As I have never met the employers, I don't know what their ages are, although I doubt they are 14 year old prodigies.

Comment: @jmac, I'm confused about why answers to my question would be opinion based when I'm specifically asking for authoritative sources on workplace etiquette (which I expect would be an etiquette guide or a similar authority). Also, [this question on how to address your boss over e-mail](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1604/8233) seems just like this question, but it wasn't marked as opinion based and I'm not seeing what is different about this one.

Comment: I made a somewhat significant edit of your question to make it more applicable to a broader audience and more likely to get good answers. If you think it no longer addresses your problem, please feel free to click the [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/13883/edit) button and revert or change it to something better. As I said in the second comment, *"If you specify your specific situation, it will likely not be so useful to future visitors."* so I focused on more general strategies on how to decide (which should be universal).

Comment: That question is quite old and most likely would get a much more critical reception if asked now. The Workplace is still in Beta, and we are still trying to figure out what works best -- I am not trying to be critical, you asked for feedback so I provided it (I was not the downvote). Feel free to ignore my advice and/or [start a meta thread](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to clarify what the guidelines should be for this type of question.

Comment: I appreciate you making the changes. It looks like you changed the title to what you suggested and took out all of the parts of my personal situation. I had added them to show that it was a real problem and not just a hypothetical situation, but if that's not the way it's done, then I'm fine with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10224/discussion-between-jmac-and-thunderforge)

Comment: I edited the title because when I read it I thought you were facing a situation where titles were called for but you didn't know the gender of your correspondent. There's no mention of that in the question, which seems to be "titles or not?" as opposed to "which title?"

Comment: You will always be correct if you use Mr with males and Ms. with females.  Ms. is proper for both married and unmarried females.  Mr. is always correct for males.  You only need to determine what sex the person is.  You always use their lastname, never address them by their firstname, its almost never approiate.

Comment: @ramhound your guidance is stated more confidently than it should be. The world is a big place and what is proper in one place may not be in another. That's the problem with this question, and answering it isn't possible without context

Comment: Someone has tagged this question [tag:united-states], but one should be aware that it's offensive to call someone who you aren't familiar with by their first name in some Asian countries. I'm sure about India, Thailand, and Mainland China. This may apply other countries from the region as well.

Comment: @Ramhound Guessing a title is a bad move, because there is no always-safe answer. In academic or computing contexts my title is "Dr" and "Ms" is definitely incorrect. I actually prefer "Patricia", and indicate that by signing e-mails that way.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Guessing a title may be inaccurate but is overall a better strategy. It works like this: if I guess "Dr. Shanahan" you can always come back and say "Just call me Patricia" and that is 100% OK by both parties. OTOH if I guess wrong and call you Patricia (but you didn't want that) then it would be awkward for you to correct it (you may want to say "Call me Dr. Shanahan" but will be disinclined to do so because it sounds too haughty).

Comment: @Brandin Either Dr. Shanahan or Patricia are correct, and if you know that picking the more formal one makes sense. I was responding to a comment that suggested always guessing either "Ms" or "Mr".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should I follow their lead, or should I err on the conservative side
>   the first time I address them to test the waters?

In the U.S. it almost never hurts to err on the conservative side when dealing with written conversation and a prospective employer.

I am sometimes taken aback when someone who I don't know and have never spoken with addresses me as "Joe". (Perhaps I'd rather be called "Joseph", perhaps in my company everyone uses full names in emails, etc)

Thus, until you are comfortably on a first-name basis with someone, address them as "Mr. [Lastname]" or "Ms. [Lastname]" in your emails.

After you have talked with them on the phone, or met them in person, you'll get a better idea as to how casual their culture is. At that time, you may feel more free to address them by their first name.

Comment: Sometimes the gender of a person being contacted electronically is not initially clear. Many people have gender-neutral first names and no indication of their gender in their e-mail signature. What should one do in this case?

Comment: @Koviko Whatever you do, don't write "Hello [Lastname]"! I'd bet you a lot that almost all emails starting thusly are just canned meat.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that this works best in communication with prospective future employers :
In the beginning of your communications, always address the 'To' person as Mr/Ms(Mz) Last name. Even though the other party may address you with your first name.
 Once you have made some progress with your aplithe prospective firm and you know the other person for a while (as opposed to talking to a team of HRs) and the other other person is addressing you by your first name, then you can address the other person with his first name Ex. Hi John.
Due to the conditions Mr.Fox talks about, over the years I have found that opening a mail just saying a simple 'Hello' to be the best way.

Comment: Although I liked Joe's answer better, I've upvoted this one because using "Hello" when you're concerned about choosing the wrong one is definitely good advice, although it is certainly less personal.

Answer (score 0):

When you answer - follow their lead. Hi John, Hi Jane, Hello Mr. Smith, Hello Ms. Doe.
When you write first - I'd say Mr./Ms. FirstName LastName would be safest. Especially when you write to foreigners and have no idea which part is their last name and which is a family-country-specific name. A friend of mine is responsible of creating email addresses for new employees with the standard jsmith routine. The ways of politely asking "Which word is your last name?"... I once referred to an Indian coworker as "Currently not in the office", because I heard he had a strange [for us] name and this is what I found in his status. So yeah, better go safe.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, start emails on the first-name basis.

If you work with people from all around the world it is very hard to adhere to the proper etiquette because you might not know where exactly the person is located or what the proper form may be. So in my humble experience, it seems that the standard that is emerging is to call people by first names. This is what I have experienced working within MNCs and in companies that use outsourcing. As per Mr. Strazzere's answer - if there are multiple name variants, use the one listed in outlook/corporate directory.

Why not use Mr/Ms/Mrs?

Some believe that women being addressed differently (Ms vs Mrs) is sexist [read here](http://users.resist.ca/~kirstena/pagemissmsmrs.html) [(example of it turning to law here)](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1162384/EU-bans-use-Miss-Mrs-sportsmen-statesmen-claims-sexist.html).

Even if the lady you're dealing with doesn't hold that viewpoint, do you really want to guess whether she is a Ms or a Mrs? Some people will get offended when you guess wrong.

What if you're dealing with a trans-gendered individual? Do you really want to go there?

Finally, at least with some people, it may be hard to guess the gender of the person from their name alone. Their names may be from different countries/cultures that are unfamiliar to you, and making that mistake will not look good.

In today's brave new world, the safest and simplest thing to do is use the first name.

Comment: I imagine that I'm far more likely to offend someone by addressing them by their first name when they don't feel it is appropriate than by using Mr or Ms when the person takes offense to the fairly neutral "Ms" or is transgender. No downvote, but I figured I'd explain why I don't think it's the right answer.

Comment: @Thunderforge Downvotes are a perfectly valid way to disagree with an answer on this website.

Comment: I always figured that downvotes were for answers that were wrong. Yours isn't really wrong, it's just that the situation is less likely to come up than others. At any rate, it's my choice whether or not I want to downvote and I choose not to.

Comment: How do you know which is their first name? I know a person named Ha Kwang Hui - how would you address him? Also - Ms. is neutral. The difference is between Mrs. and Miss.

Comment: @Karolina I don't think Ha Kwang Hui is a very good example because I can't tell if they're a Mr. or a Ms. anyway. Is there a problem with just using their full name in this case?

Comment: @MasterOfBinary For me it's not a problem, but I don't know if there is any formal advice on that. That's why I addressed only the part I knew.